# UIScrollView top very low

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

In my storyboard I have a label and a UIScrollView subclass with the scrollview constraints placing it directly under the label:

[image: UIScrollView under label in storyboard]

In code I am adding a single view that will have the content:

```
let contentView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 2000, 1000))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    tableView.addSubview(contentView)
}

func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return contentView
}
```

When the scrollView shows, the top is not up against the label:

[image: Simulator view, scrollView is far below label]

Why isn't the scrollview up against the label?

Comment: Look up "automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your view controller...

```
Self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're saying it is now working or not. What error are you getting? Or is it working?